# Is sun.misc.vm still available in Java 11?

Tags: java

I am migrating a project from Java 8 to OpenJDK 11. Some code is still using **sun.misc.VM**. When I try to compile it by adding the exports from the **jdk.unsupported** module, I get the following error:

```
javac --add-exports jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED C:\mypath\mysoure.java
    C:\mypath\mysoure.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
    import sun.misc.VM;
                   ^
      symbol:   class VM
      location: package sun.misc
```

Also when I browse through the **jdk.unsupported.jmod** file, I can't find VM under the classes\sun\misc\ path. Is it really gone ore maybe still contained in another module?

Comment: From my knowledge `sun` pack it is from `Oracle`. `OpenJDK` don't contains libraries from `Oracle`, atleast in `OpenJDK 11`.

Comment: What do you need this class for?  Have you looked into an alternative?

Comment: @VGR: As an integrator I want to get a huge code base through the build first. It's not my code. Need to get an overview first, what kind of changes are required as part of Java 11 migration. Might run across a number of other issues during the build. Still analysing on the actual migration plan.

Comment: @KunLun : OpenJDK still contains e. g. sun.misc.Signal in the same module.

Comment: Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53543062/replace-access-to-sun-misc-vm-for-jdk-11)